# show near by restaurants in Map View using user current location in map kit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mapkit, mapkitannotation

In my iphone app,I have to show near by restaurants in Map View.

But how can I show nearby restaurants with in 5000 meters of current location with native MKMap view(I found out my current location-lat&long)

I would like to learn how to implement as in the below screen shot(by clicking the annotations going to its detail too)

[image]

Comment: you need a good data source (like some api) which support geo location search

Comment: note that these days **you very simply use MKLocalSearchRequest** to do this on iOS, it is as easy as can be

Answer (score 0):

You can use foursquare API as one possibility.
https://developer.foursquare.com/

1. fetch venues from API

   ```
   var venues: Array = fetchVenues()
   ```
2. Make annotation

   ```
       var venueAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
       venueAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(venue.latitude!, venue.longitude!)
       venueAnnotation.title = venue.name
       venueAnnotation.subtitle = venue.address
   ```
3. Add annotation to MapView

   ```
       self?.mapView.addAnnotation(venueAnnotation)
   ```

This site might be helpful to you.

iOS Development: Near me Places- (FourSquare API) http://prashantpatil26.blogspot.jp/2014/06/near-me-places-foursquare-api.html

Comment: note that these days you **very simply use MKLocalSearchRequest to do this on iOS**, it is as easy as can be